# Nesting DevExpress FormLayout inside of a formview Item Template

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, devexpress

I am in the process of working on a new part of a project where they want the details of an agreement to which a bill is attached to be displayed inside of one of the elements in the  element of a WebForms project. I am running into the following error screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll4PY.png)

Since I did not need to have the edit functionality of a full formview, I attempted to accomplish this by nesting a Dev Express ASPX Form Layout element inside of the Item Template, calling on the value of a hidden field (id="StorageAgreementId") to populate a collection of labels arranged into a layout inside of the layout field.

That form layout is supposed to call on the Database after the Storage Bill information is obtained by utilizing an Object Data Source which utilizes the control defined inside of the Item Template directly after the FormLayout in the markup. Below is the markup:

[Markup for the parts I find relevant to the functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4J0M.png)

This all makes sense to me so far, and when I didn't set the binding for the elements that were to be databound, the form layout appeared exactly the way I wanted it to look, so I know it isn't the layout itself. The next step I took was to select each of the labels and apply the databinding through the tasks context menu as shown in the below image:

[image of the ItemTemplate as well as the cell of the table in which I placed the FormLayout and the ODS it is referencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6egy.png)

This is when the error occurred. The thing I find odd is that the error does NOT occur when the Agreement is the only field shown in the formlayout (tested by commenting out and eliminating offending parts)

I'm primarily an MVC guy so I'm not sure what is missing or if I need to do something special in the codebehind (VB.Net), especially since the DataBound Combo Box I put in the editItemTemplate worked so well, though it doesn't need a control to run with a parameterless query

DevExpress version for the project is 17.1

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the BEST solution to the problem, but it did work for me, and so I will answer the question in case someone ever has this kind of job to do, since I was unable to find an answer on SO before.

What I did to fix the problem was to create an empty formview element inside of the Item Template. I added a new Item Template to the Formview as shown here:

```html
<td class="TableValueCell" colspan="3">
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsStorageAgreement" DataKeyNames="Id">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="StorageAgreementDisplay" runat="server" ColCount="3" DataSourceID="odsStorageAgreement" EnableTheming="True" Theme="Office2010Silver">
                <!-- insert contents here -->
            </dx:ASPxFormLayout>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</td>
```

In the design view it looks like this:

[image: Design View Solution]

I will certainly be following to see if anyone comes up with their own solutions because I'm not foolish enough to think myself the first to ever run into this issue. If you have an alternative that might be less of a bodge, let me know. It was an issue the program designer himself hadn't run into before, so I'm definitely open to things being improved somehow